# Position absolute right when parent has scroll

Tags: html, css

I want the `green` element to stay at `absolute right position` of it's parent (`orange`) container. But if using the horizontal scroll it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? How to keep the `green` element always at right position?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.stay-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="stay-right"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you arent just applying the `overflow: scroll;` to `.inner` ?

Comment: @schrej good question. Yes, the reason is that the outer is resizable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need a another container where the green bar would be outside the scrolling container.

However one thing is that I have manually reduced the height of green bar to not overlap on horizontal scrollbar, might have to look at it again.

```css
* {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .outer-main{
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
    }

    .outer {
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      background-color: orange;
      width: 400px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow-x: scroll;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .stay-right {
      position: absolute;
      right: -19px;
      top: 0px;
      border: solid 1px black;
      background-color: green;
      width: 20px;
      height:100%;
      z-index: 1
    }

    .inner {
      width: 600px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="outer-main">
    <div class="stay-right"></div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Chetan, +1 and if not better answers will occur I will accept in the near future!

Comment: @caramba, you are welcome! I have also changed it a little so to avoid the manual bottom value, but here the green bar feels outside the scrollbar. Either way can be done.

Comment: Thanks again, in my case that's luckily exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your scroller outside your text.
Here is an example:

CSS

```
.parent-to-position-by {
    position: relative;
}

.scrolling-contents {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.scrolling-inner{
  min-width: 600px;
}

.fixed-elements {
  width: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: orange;
}

.fixed {
    position: absolute; /* effectively fixed */
    top: 0;
    right: 100%;
    background-color: #F00;
    width: 20px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="parent-to-position-by">
  <div class="fixed-elements">
      <div class="fixed">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scrolling-contents">
    <div class="scrolling-inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is also a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/CaAMJmG8QJL0jG8DyGOz?p=preview) to working example.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a flexbox. Unless there are other reasons you want to use `position: absolute;` i would recommend that way. This also requires another div like Chetan's solution.
Flexbox isn't supported by as much browsers as `position: absolute;` if that is a requirement.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: horizontal;
}

.stay-right {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.inner {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner-text {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="inner-text">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="stay-right"></div>
</div>
```